# How to inspect website running on smart TV browser?

Tags: debugging, browser, cross-browser, samsung-smart-tv, samsung-internet

I have a website running on a Samsung TV browser and I would like to inspect its network. Couldn't do it through Tizen Studio because it's not a project I'm working on, it's just a website running on Samsung Internet app. Is there a way to inspect it remotely?

Answer (score 1):

- first of all, you have to bookmark a website it could be any website
- head to bookmarks and edit the bookmarked website
- find the Name input and name it "inspect element"
- find the URL input, copy and paste the following script into it

```
javascript:(() => {var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda";document.body.appendChild(script);script.onload = (() => eruda.init());})()
```

- save and go to the website you want to use inspect element on
- on the same website search for "inspect element" it should pop up in the bookmarks section
- Press it and a settings icon should appear
- enjoy :)

You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdW_8AFpHSw) for reference

it worked on a phone but not on an LG TV as I see it but can't click it so you could try if it worked that's great

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33409146)

Comment: You're right, sorry I'm new. I'll add right now